# Please, is a comma required after the word 'lists'?

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

I have written many poems, topped lists and helped other poets.

Also, is a comma required after the word 'wells' here?

I spent years trimming flowers, digging wells and doing dishes.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.businessinsider.com/a-guide-to-proper-comma-use-2013-9. Check the number **4** on the list, that should help :).

Comment: From the tags, it appears that you are familiar with the Oxford comma/ serial comma. So what really is the problem? Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Welcome to SE! You're heading into controversial territory. ^_^ Could you elaborate and include why you think a comma might or might not be needed?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your comments are great. It helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the comma you mention is known as the Oxford Comma. Users of the English language have traditionally been split into opposing camps over the validity and usefulness; now it has largely come to be accepted as valid. While not required, the Oxford Comma may come in handy for avoiding ambiguities or emphasising the final item on a list. In your second example, for instance, 'digging wells and doing dishes' may be taken as an elaboration of 'trimming flowers' (compare to 'I spent years frequenting movie theaters, watching crime thrillers and taking copious notes'); if you add the Oxford Comma, this ambiguity disappears.

Comment: See my comment at OP.